# Apply try/except with df.loc in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply a filter in python with try/except. How can I do it? I mean something like 'try to filter de csv, if you can't because `'ON'` or `'OFF'` are not in rows `df_ok = df`'

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('a.csv')

try:
    df_ok = df.loc[df['Precio'] != 'ON']
    df_ok = df_ok.loc[df_ok['Precio'] != 'OFF']
```

csv:

```
    Espacio País Precio
0   4083496    *     ON
1   4083554    *    OFF
2   4083368    *     ON
3   4083194    *    OFF
4   4083194    *     ON
5   4083194    *    OFF
6   4083194    *     ON
7   4083194    *     ON
8    MARTIN    *    0.5
9    MARTIN    *     89
10   MARTIN    *    198
```

Comment: `try/except` is not the same as `if/else`. `try` blocks are used for the case that an `Exception` may be raised, and it can be handled accordingly. You are looking for an `if` statement

Comment: what do you want to happen if those columns aren't there?  Fill with empty data?  pass?

Comment: Your title is very misleading, You don't want try/except. You want to filter with a logical expression. Or else `groupby`

Answer (score 3):

Here is one method:

```
df

Out[110]: 
    Espacio País Precio
0   4083496    *     ON
1   4083554    *    OFF
2   4083368    *     ON
3   4083194    *    OFF
4   4083194    *     ON
5   4083194    *    OFF
6   4083194    *     ON
7   4083194    *     ON
8    MARTIN    *    0.5
9    MARTIN    *     89
10   MARTIN    *    198

df[~df['Precio'].str.contains('ON|OFF')]

Out[111]: 
   Espacio País Precio
8   MARTIN    *    0.5
9   MARTIN    *     89
10  MARTIN    *    198
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be better suited with the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('a.csv')

filtered_df = df[df['Precio']=='ON' | df['Precio']=='OFF']

# Then check if filtered_df is empty
```

Comment: Agreed, then you can do:

if filtered_df.empty:
    pass
else:
   print('not empty')
   "do other stuff needed"

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is selkect all rows where Precio is not one of 'ON' and 'OFF'

```
df[~df['Precio'].isin(['ON','OFF'])]
Out[111]: 
   Espacio País Precio
8   MARTIN    *    0.5
9   MARTIN    *     89
10  MARTIN    *    198
```